# Could not cast value of type UITabBarController to FirstViewController (xCode 6.4)

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to pass variables from a view controller to another one. First, there's a connection screen. When the infos are verified, then I pass the username and other data to the whole program (that has a tab bar controller).

Here is the code. I'm using Xcode 6.4. In the previous version, the page would open but the variables didn't pass. Now it just gives me the above error.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "lienConnecte") {
            let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController // this line was just an attempt to find a solution
            let vueFil = segue.destinationViewController as! FirstViewController

            vueFil.utilisateur = utilisateur 
        }
    }
```

Of course I know that in the storyboard, the segue points to the tab bar controller (because I need it afterwards), but I want the values to be passed to the FirstControllerView

Found the solution, for those who will see this post:

```
let tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
let vueFil = tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as! FirstViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot turn one thing into another, like some sort of magician, by saying `as`. You have to get a reference to the *actual* thing you're after. If there's a FirstViewController that is one of the child view controllers of the UITabBarController, then first get a reference to the UITabBarController (which you already know how to do), and then obtain its `viewControllers` property — those are its children, and you can, from there, get the one you want by its index number.

Answer (score 0):

Your tab view controller is a container view controller that owns child view controllers. Presumably, `FirstViewController` is one of these child view controllers. Therefore, your tab view controller and your `FirstViewController` are different instances. You can access a tab bar's children with the `viewControllers` property:

```
let firstVC = tabVC.viewControllers?.first
// firstVC should be your FirstViewController
```

Comment: it doesn't work...
    `let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController

    let vueFil: AnyObject? = nav.viewControllers?.first`